# why does mov %ax, %ds assemble+disassemble as mov %eax,%ds, inconsistent with the original?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, objdump, memory-segmentation

test.S

```
.text
.global _start
    _start:
        xor %ax, %ax
        mov %ax, %ds
        mov %ax, %ss
        mov %ax, %es
        mov %ax, %fs
        mov %ax, %gs
```

I got the disassembly code file by doing this

```
$ x86_64-elf-gcc -g -c -O0 -m32 -fno-pie -fno-stack-protector -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables .\test.S
$ x86_64-elf-ld .\test.o -m elf_i386  -Ttext=0x7c00 -o test.elf
$ x86_64-elf-objdump -x -d -S -m i386 ./test.elf > test_dis.txt
```

test_dis.txt

```
./test.elf:     file format elf32-i386
./test.elf
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x00007c00

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00007000 paddr 0x00007000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000c0d memsz 0x00000c0d flags r-x

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000000d  00007c00  00007c00  00000c00  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .debug_aranges 00000020  00000000  00000000  00000c10  2**3
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  2 .debug_info   00000049  00000000  00000000  00000c30  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  3 .debug_abbrev 00000014  00000000  00000000  00000c79  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  4 .debug_line   0000003b  00000000  00000000  00000c8d  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
SYMBOL TABLE:
00007c00 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 00000000 .debug_aranges
00000000 l    d  .debug_info    00000000 .debug_info
00000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  00000000 .debug_abbrev
00000000 l    d  .debug_line    00000000 .debug_line
00007c00 g       .text  00000000 _start
00008c0d g       .text  00000000 __bss_start
00008c0d g       .text  00000000 _edata
00008c10 g       .text  00000000 _end



Disassembly of section .text:

00007c00 <_start>:
.text
.global _start
    _start:
        xor %ax, %ax
    7c00:   66 31 c0                xor    %ax,%ax
        mov %ax, %ds
    7c03:   8e d8                   mov    %eax,%ds
        mov %ax, %ss
    7c05:   8e d0                   mov    %eax,%ss
        mov %ax, %es
    7c07:   8e c0                   mov    %eax,%es
        mov %ax, %fs
    7c09:   8e e0                   mov    %eax,%fs
    7c0b:   8e e8                   mov    %eax,%gs
```

---

## My question

I wonder why I got code like this `mov %eax,%ds`, which doesn't fit my original assembly code? Why does objdump output paradoxical results

## My expectation

I expect `mov %eax,%ds` should be `mov %ax,%ds`, and I don't think `%eax`(32 bits) fits `%ds`(16 bits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions `mov %eax, %ds` and `mov %ax, %ds` do the exact same thing (you could say they are really the same instruction), except that the former has a shorter encoding due to a missing `66` prefix byte.  The assembler kindly picks the shorter encoding for you while the disassembler artificially distinguishes the two through a different register size.

Comment: Thank you, and I noticed that this is a special optimization for `mov` which contains a segment register. It is also valid `mov %ds,%eax`

Comment: @Markity Not exactly: `mov %ds, %ax` leaves the high 16 bit of `%eax` unchanged while `mov %ds, %eax` clears them.  Prefer `mov %ds, %eax` in 32 bit mode unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov documents that `mov %ds, %eax` is only guaranteed to zero the upper 16 bits of EAX on Pentium Pro and later, on Intel CPUs.  (@Markity).  At least I think that's what they mean by `MOV Reg, Sreg` (Intel syntax) in that case, with 32-bit operand-size not 16.  I tested on my Skylake CPU in 64-bit mode.  `66 8c d8 mov ax, ds` leaves the upper 16 bits unmodified, `8c d8  mov eax, ds` does zero them as expected.  So apparently on P5 Pentium and earlier, `mov %ds, %eax`  (AT&T) wouldn't necessarily zero-extend.

Comment: @PeterCordes Uh... I dimly recall there was something like this.  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I also learned recently that `mov` with a segreg and a memory operand always treats the latter as an `m16`, regardless what prefixes are included. An `osize` prefix is allowed from the assembler, but does not affect the word size of the memory operand in any way. I had to add that to my debugger's assembler and disassembler in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/912356bc7941 and its two parent changesets. @PeterCordes cited the possibility that `mov` from segreg to 32-bit registers may not zero the upper half. Unlike the memory operand, the selected `osize` is used for the `r16/r32` operand.

Comment: @ecm: Indeed, Intel's manual does show this in the table of opcodes: there's a form `MOV r16/r32/m16, Sreg` and a REX.W version `MOV r64/m16, Sreg`.  Note the m16, unlike when I commented on https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/33826 in 2017, when Intel's manual said `MOV r/m64,Sreg`. The Description section doesn't mention that memory destination ignores the operand-size attribute.  `objdump -d` does know that, though: it prints `rex.W mov WORD PTR [rsp],ds` for the result of assembling NASM `mov qword [rsp], ds`, which `ndisasm -b64` disassembles "incorrectly" back to the same source.

Comment: @PeterCordes https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/912356bc7941 quotes a foot note as "In 32-bit mode, the assembler may insert the 16-bit operand-size prefix with this instruction", implying that it is a no-op, albeit it does not explicitly state that the memory operand is always `m16`. The NASM version I'm using (close to 2.16rc10) rejects `mov dword [100h], es` in both `bits 16` and `bits 32` modes, `mov [100h], es` and `mov word [100h], es` are both accepted but never emit an `osize` prefix in either bitness mode. ndisasm will emit an `o32` or `o16` prefix keyword.